# Setting number of decimals in formatting programmatically

Tags: scala

I have the following Double in Scala:

```
val value: Double = 12.34
```

and get the formatted value, like so:

```
val formatted = f"$value%1.5f"
```

But I need to set the number of decimals (above 5) programmatically. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
val dec = 8
val formatted = f"$value%1.decf"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val value: Double = 12.34
val dec = 8
val formatted = s"%1.${dec}f".format(value) // 12.34000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scala `BigDecimal` with its `setScale` def then convert to a `Double` if necessary:

```
BigDecimal(12.35564126).setScale(5, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
// res0: Double = 12.35564
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
fmt="%."+n+"f"
fmt.format(12.34)
```

Too obvious?